# Converting a CM Synergy archive to free source control

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial, cm-synergy

Because of downsizing and cost-saving our organisation is moving from CM/Telogic/Rational Synergy to free tools (most probably SVN). Is there anyway to transfer history and branch information from Synergy to a free tool?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a native way to dump/import a CM Synergy source base into another SCM, which means the usual "generic import" tactic applies:

- select some important baselines/labels/branches and load them one by one on the hard drive.
- for each baseline, use that image as source to copy the files over the working directory of the target SCM (SVN or Git, [Git can handle that kind of scenario very easily](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33868/script-tool-to-import-series-of-snapshots-each-being-a-new-edition-into-git-po/33880#33880)).
- commit, then repeat for the next baseline/label/branch

But that means you loose some history and some metadata along the way.

Answer (score 1):

There's something going on in regards to CM/Synergy to git conversion over on github: https://github.com/emanuelez/PySynergy

Comment: Is there some documentation on how to use those python scripts to convert a synergy database to a Git repository?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/24eme/eurocontrol_synergy2git was a migration project.

The dump part has worked. The CM synergy dumps are still used to investigate history of an object. The script my_cfs is still used to recreate an old version of a project.

Answer (score -2):

For a few customers, I have converted CM/synergy to Git based on the project's static revisions respecting the logical history and adding meta-data (baseline, task, objects etc info) to git tags, so it is searchable.

Secondly I respected the subproject structure using submodules( or convert to directories) . It is using a variant of http://www.2git.io/ ( created by [www.praqma.com](http://www.praqma.com) / https://github.com/Praqma/2git  ) supporting Synergy..

Details of the migration are described here: https://www.eficode.com/blog/migrate-from-synergy-to-git

In addition to Synergy to Git, I also migrated Change to Jira

Update: The company Praqma is now part of [www.eficode.com](http://www.eficode.com)

My approach is quite robust of handling / disgarding Synergy usage issues..

Comment: Soliciting off-site contacts is not acceptable here. You are free to add your contact details to your profile if you like, but your answers should remain strictly public answers.

Comment: Please don't post [duplicate answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51627456) If these two questions are really that similar, they should be marked as duplicates.