# Migrating PySynergy to GIT

Tags: git, cm-synergy

Has anyone tried migratePySynergy to GIT? Have you been able to migrate including the history?

My company is planning a Synergy to GIT migration.
I have found the PySynergy project on Github and trying to use it.

I had to adapt it for our environment and fix some small issues.
But I see I'm unable to migrate the source code to GIT with the code tree.

Has anyone tried this migration, including the code tree?
Any suggestions / references?

Comment: This question is the only Google hit for "migratePySynergy". Do you have a link? The README for [PySynergy](https://github.com/emanuelez/PySynergy) says "If you need assistance or help in migrating from Synergy to git, don't hesitate to contact me at [e-mail address].

Answer (score 3):

For a customer, I have converted CM/synergy to Git based on the project's static revisions respecting the logical history and adding meta-data (baseline, task, objects etc info) to git tags, so it is searchable.

Secondly I respected the subproject structure using submodules ( or converted to directories). It is using a variant of http://www.2git.io/ ( created by [www.praqma.com](http://www.praqma.com) / https://github.com/Praqma/2git  ) supporting Synergy..

My approach is quite robust of handling / disgarding Synergy usage issues..

Answer (score 0):

I once spent a good deal of time trying to use it and failed. The script is very tied to how nokia had their code organized and it depends on which version of synergy you are on and how it was used. I ran into 3 main problems: 1. We were stuck on old 32 bit systems that did not work with the multi-threaded aspect of pySynergy. this is easy to fix. 2. We did not use the same version and the script expect fields we didn't have. 3. We did some funky things that broke the continuity in baselines.

I gave up and used a list of baselines, and feed them to a script that created a git repo, then grabbed each of the baselines, created a list of tasks between the previous baseline and committed with a message listing the tasks. It was imperfect but it actually worked well enough. Our history was all jacked in synergy before the migration so we didn't lose too much. Good luck! I wish I still had access to the scripts so you could leverage some of the queries.